# How can i pass the parameters in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, function, view, parameters, controller

I'm getting de geolocation of the user in this way and thats working y can see it in the view with {{lat}} and {{lng}} :

```
    (function () {
        var showController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

            $scope.showPosition = function (position) {
                $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                $scope.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                $scope.$apply();

            }

            $scope.showError = function (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        $scope.error = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        $scope.error = "Location information is unavailable."
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        $scope.error = "The request to get user location timed out."
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        $scope.error = "An unknown error occurred."
                        break;
                }
                console.log ("error geo "+$scope.error);
                $scope.$apply();
            }

            $scope.getLocation = function () {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition, $scope.showError);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.error = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            $scope.getLocation();

/** Here says lat and lng undefinied*/
$scope.showTrends = function() {
                var url;

                if ($scope.error) {
                    url = "http://localhost:3000/trends?id=23424747"
                }
                else {
                    url = "http://localhost:3000/myplace?lat="+$scope.lat+"&long="+$scope.lng;
                    console.log(url);
                }

                $http.get(url)
                    .then(function(res){
                        $scope.trends = res.data[0].trends;
                        console.log(res.data[0].trends);
                    })
            }

}
})
```

Now, i need to choose between differents urls based on location results. I have this code but doen't work because it says that lat and lng is undefinied 
Maybe i'm just calling the latitude and long in the wrong

I'm calling it in the view like

```
<section ng-init="showTrends()"></section>
```

Comment: Is the code defining the $scope.showTrends function under the <section> tag in your HTML?

Comment: no no, i have all the js code showed in my controller and the section tag is just for showing the way that i'm calling it in my view

Comment: "Doesn't work" : does that mean that $scope.lat is undefined ? Is your `showTrends` function in the same controller ?

Comment: yes, it says undefined for latitude and longitude. and all functions are in the same controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did it ! this is my new code in the view controller

```
(function () {
    var trendsController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $q) {                

        $scope.trends = [];
        var latitude = 0, longitude = 0, placeId=0,trd = this;

        this.getLocation = function() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(trd.getTrends);
            } else { 
                console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        }

        this.getTrends = function(position) {
            getPlaceId(position)
            .then(function(id) {
                placeId = id;
                getTrendList(placeId)
                .then(function(trends){
                    $scope.trends = trends;
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });     
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        };

        getTrendList = function(placeId) {
            var def = $q.defer(),
            trendList = [];

            $http.get("http://localhost:3000/trends?id="+placeId)
                .success(function(response){
                    trendList = response[0].trends;
                    def.resolve(trendList);
                }).error(function(){
                    def.reject("Failed to get trend list");
                });

            return def.promise;
        }


        getPlaceId = function (position) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude, 
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            $http.get("http://localhost:3000/myplace?lat="+latitude+"&long="+longitude).success(function(response){
                placeId = response[0].woeid;
                def.resolve(placeId);
            }).error(function(){
                def.reject("Failed to get id location");
            });
            return def.promise;
        }

        trd.getLocation();

    }

    trendsController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams","$q"];
    angular.module("tweeterApp").controller("trendsController", trendsController);

}());
```